# How can I research how a film quote was translated into Japanese?

Tags: resources

Are there any websites that lists Japanese-language translation quotes of English-language  films? For example, how would I find out how `English, mother******, do you speak it?` from "Pulp Fiction" was translated?

Comment: Borrowing a DVD/blueray movie and watch Japanese subtitle while hearing English will be fast.

Answer (score 6):

Sawa's recommendation that you borrow or rent the movies and look these things up is the best one, because I seriously doubt there's a site that would offer what you're looking for as a matter of course.

However, *just this once*, because you caught me just at the right time, I'll just tell you what the translation is. I felt like making it an exercise of my listening abilities, so we can both win.

Note that this is what Jules says in the dubbed version. Subtitles can and often do differ.

Also note that this is how I heard it. If any native speakers catch some errors, please let me know.

Last note: I'm only going to translate the bits that reflect the difference between the Japanese and English versions. The rest I think you can work out if you want.

**Jules:** お前、国はどこだ？ ("What country are you from?" This was originally "Do you speak English")

**Brett:** なっ...何？

**Jules:** 何って国どこもねぇぞ！

**Jules:** テメエ、アメリカ人だる？　("Are you American, motherfucker?" This is the line that was originally "English, motherfucker, do you speak it?")

**Brett:** えぇ？

**Jules:** アメリカだよ！テメエはアメリカじんだろや？！

**Brett:** そうです！

**Jules:** じゃ、俺の言っていること分かっているか？

**Brett:** そうです！

**Jules:** じゃ、言っているよ。マーセラス・ワラスはどんな姿形の男だった？

And it goes on from there.

Hope that helps.